# Why does React think that my class method is hook?

Tags: reactjs

Just updated react from v16 to v17 and got error, that Failed to compile.

```
 Line 37:9:  React Hook "Api.useAuth" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render                                                                      react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
 Line 47:9:  React Hook "Api.useAuth" is called in function "loginInApp" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

My code like

```
import Api from 'utils/api';

// AuthContext.Provider
const AuthProvider = (props: any) => {

    if (existingToken) {
        Api.useAuth(existingToken);
    }

    ... other code

    const loginInApp = (token: string) => {
        Api.useAuth(token);
    };

}
```

in /utils/api

```
class Api {
    ... other code

    useAuth = (token: string) => {
        this.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    };
}

const api = new Api();

export default api;
```

I absolutely don't understand, why it is and what I should do.

Comment: It's because the method name starts with "use"

Comment: Because you are using the keyword  "use"

Comment: lol that is! Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `eslint` wants to check for `Hooks rules` it doesn't understand your class or your other method and it will not try to do that because it's a heavy process. it just checks if your methods starts with `use` or not. just change your class method name and you're good to go:

```
class Api {
    ... other code

    auth = (token: string) => {
        this.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    };
}
```

Comment: React doesn't check anything, it's eslint which only parsing the file's content.